# How to convert XML text to a tag?

Tags: xml, xslt

Could anyone show me how to use XSLT to put the text from the tag into a tag name?

**XML:**

```
<a>
   Some topic:
</a>
<b>
   Some text on the topic.
</b>
```

**Needed result:**

```
<Some_topic>
    Some text on the topic.
</Some_topic>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this XML

```
<xml>
<a>
   Some topic:
</a>
<b>
   Some text on the topic.
</b>
</xml>
```

Use this XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name='element' select="translate( normalize-space( /xml/a ), ' :', '_')"/>
    <xsl:element name='{$element}'>
        <xsl:value-of select='/xml/b'/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To produce

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Some_topic>
   Some text on the topic.
</Some_topic>
```

Let me know what I grade I get on your homework assignment -ha ha